# How to restart nuodb managed database after OS crash

Tags: nuodb

I'm using nuodb-ce 2.4

I created a empty managed database (called `testdb`) using automation console (template `Single Host`), however when OS crash (or restart) database disappear.

I checked `ls /var/opt/nuodb/production-archives/testdb/`

```
1.atm   12.cat  16.atm  19.atm  22.atm  25.atm  29.atm  32.atm  35.atm  4.atm   43.atm  46.cat  5.atm   52.cat  56.atm  59.atm  61.atm  65.atm  7.atm       fingerprints.dat
10.atm  13.atm  16.cat  2.atm   22.cat  26.atm  3.atm   32.cat  36.atm  40.atm  44.atm  47.atm  50.atm  53.atm  56.cat  6.atm   62.atm  66.atm  8.atm       journal
10.cat  14.atm  17.atm  20.atm  23.atm  27.atm  30.atm  33.atm  37.atm  41.atm  44.cat  48.atm  50.cat  54.atm  57.atm  6.cat   62.cat  66.cat  8.cat       state.dat
11.atm  14.cat  18.atm  20.cat  24.atm  28.atm  30.cat  34.atm  38.atm  42.atm  45.atm  48.cat  51.atm  54.cat  58.atm  60.atm  63.atm  67.atm  9.atm
12.atm  15.atm  18.cat  21.atm  24.cat  28.cat  31.atm  34.cat  39.atm  42.cat  46.atm  49.atm  52.atm  55.atm  58.cat  60.cat  64.atm  68.atm  cloud_time.dat
```

`nuodb [domain] > show domain summary`

```
Hosts:
[broker] * ce2384664ad0/localhost:48004 (DEFAULT_REGION) CONNECTED
```

And same nothing on web console

[image]

`nuodb [domain] > start database testdb`

```
Timeout (ms/s/m/h/d/w) (optional):
unknown database [testdb]
```

`bin/nuochk /var/opt/nuodb/production-archives/testdb/`

```
Validating Schema SYSTEM ID 4
Archive verification found no issues.
```

How can I restore after crash?

---

PS if I try to recreate `SM` I have following error

```
Failed to introduce local node: Starting process [Node SM db=[testdb] pid=498 id=-1 req=null (local)] would exceed Community Edition license restrictions. Contact support@nuodb.com or visit http://doc.nuodb.com/display/doc/NuoDB+Editions to upgrade...
```

---

**Update**

After some tests I saw that `Raft` folder was not persisted during restart. After persisting it, database is not present on web-console but not started.

**However when I try to start it, I had a `400` error database is already started** but no process (`SM` and `TE`) exists

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell from what is provided on what platform you are using or what you mean by os crash.  The domain state that identifies managed databases is in /var/opt/nuodb/Raft directory.  It seems from what you mention here that that directory is not present after reboot.

You can recover your managed database with:

nuodbmgr --command "restore database dbname testdb variables 'HOST localhost'"